# Apache Sling - how to escape character in username

Tags: apache, sling, jackrabbit

Currently I'm using UserManager API to create/delete/changePassword
Reference: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/managing-users-and-groups-jackrabbit-usermanager.html

If my username don't have any special character, it works perfectly (for any create, delete, changePassword action)

But when I create an username like '**someone@somemail.com**', Sling can create a user,  but cannot do any delete or changing user password. The response return **200 OK** but the resource is still stay in GetListUser.

Executing the ChangePassword or Delete POST with **/system/userManager/user/someone@somemail.com.changePassword.json** will result in Sling create another user '**someone@somemail.com.changePassword**' in UserList.
And I cannot delete this user too.

Is there anyway to escape theses characters in username, and how to delete these bad created resources ?

**Update Apr 26th, 2016:**
I've tried '%40' instead of '@', but it created another user, and have to authentcation with 'user%40mail.com'.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, can you file one at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING?